# 5 fixed div, with relative div over them

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a fixed header, fixed left menu, fixed right menu and fixed footer with scrollable content in the middle. I did this code below, however I don't know how to put the dropdown over the other DIVs. It's always behind everything even with z-index at 10.

```
<header>
    <div id="dropdown"></div>
</header>

<div id="menuleft"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="menuright"></div>

<footer></footer>
```

Check this here with css : http://jsfiddle.net/hdkmvxhb/26/

Comment: What dropdown do you mean, a navigation / select menu?

Comment: It will be like a dropdown menu.

Comment: First of all, if all of the general-structure's elements are fixed, they could all be absolute instead. Behaviors are more understandable that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for this
use following Css
For demo check this:  http://jsfiddle.net/nikkirs/tge195y8/19/

```
header{
width:100%;
    height:49px;
    position:fixed;
    background:#000;
}
.container{
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    min-height:400px;
    padding-top: 50px
}
.left_container{
position:fixed;   
    width:30%;
    border-right:1px solid #000;
     min-height:400px;
    left:0px;
}
.middle_container{
  width:30%;  
     min-height:400px;
    float: left;
}
.right_container{
    position:fixed;
     width:30%;
     border-left:1px solid #000;
     min-height:400px;
    right:0px;
}
footer{
    position:fixed;
    height:30px;
    background:#000;
    width:100%;
}
ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
ul li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;

}
ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
display:none;
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;

}
ul li ul li { 
  background: #555; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: It's not possible to do this without the container ?

Comment: you can remove container and give footer{
bottom:0
}
but best exercise to make structure of divs with parent container

Comment: Any idea why I'm not able to do what you did : http://jsfiddle.net/hdkmvxhb/39/ ? When I put the top:100px in #dropdown it doesn't work... if I remove it... it works.

Comment: If you want to show #dropdown over the middle div then make it position:absolute and make #content z-index:-9999

http://jsfiddle.net/nikkirs/hdkmvxhb/56/

Answer (score 0):

**[FS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1gwjuc2x/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <div id="dropdown-mouseover"></div>
</header>
<div id="menuleft">Menu left</div>
<div id="menuright">Menu Right</div>
<div id="content">
The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
</div>

<footer>Footer</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
header
{
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background: #FC7474;
    padding:20px;
    width:100%;
}
#menuleft
{
    position: fixed;
    left:0px;
    top:40px;
        width: 40px; 
      background: green;
    padding:5px;
    height:100%;
}
#menuright
{
    position: fixed;
    right:0px;
    top:40px;
        width: 40px; 
      background: green;
    padding:5px;
    height:100%;
}
#content
{
    padding: 50px;
}
footer
{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    background:#000;
    padding:20px;
    width:100%;
    color: #fff;
}
```

**[FS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1gwjuc2x/1/)**

Comment: You realize that the content lies hidden underneath `footer`

Comment: I know Roko C. Buljan, But @Hugues Simon asking fixed 'footer'.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `HTML` code to the following one. Also, I have replaced your `#dropdown {` CSS with `dropdown {`

HTML:

```
<header>
    <div id="dropdown">
        <select>
            <option value="0">Select</option>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</header>
<div id="menuleft"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="menuright"></div>

<footer></footer>
```

CSS:

```
header {
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   height: 25px;
   background-color: gray;
}

select {
    position: absolute;
}
```

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8vcq0mov/)

Comment: @Hugues Simon: Do you mean this?

Comment: Not really: http://jsfiddle.net/hdkmvxhb/26/ .. I changed my jsfiddle, so you understand better. You will see there that my #dropdown isn't visible... it's under all the other DIVs. (it works on IE but not in Chrome).